# How 3 different `a` links, open 3 different divs

Tags: jquery, html

I have 3 links a which looks like buttons and I want to show a div text below, when I click on each of them. So 3 links `a`, 3 `div` texts. I must use jquery and I don't know which method is better. With class=active or with style="display:none"?

My code is below:

```
<div class="col-xs-4">
  <div class="packet-offer" id="Basic">
    <div class="vertical-middle">
      <a class="tab-link col-xs-12" href="#tab_Basic">Basic</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="col-xs-4">
  <div class="packet-offer" id="Extra">
    <div class="vertical-middle">
      <a class="tab-link col-xs-12" href="#tab_Extra">Extra</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="col-xs-4">
  <div class="packet-offer" id="Premium">
    <div class="vertical-middle">
      <a class="tab-link col-xs-12" href="#tab_Premium">Premium</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="tab-boxes" id="tab_Basic">
  <div class="damageDetails">
    <h2 class="title results_found" id="results_found">Found <strong>15</strong>
    offers in the category Basic from <strong>98,97</strong>, and they have:</h2>
    <div class="row" style="margin-bottom: 40px;">
      <span class="col-xs-6 col-sm-4 col-md-3 standar-offers">
      <i class="fa fa-check"></i>Human resources</span>
      <span class="col-xs-6 col-sm-4 col-md-3 standar-offers">
      <i class="fa fa-check"></i>Natural damages</span>
    </div>
  </div><!--damageDetails-->
</div><!--tab_Basic-->
<div class="tab-boxes" id="tab_Extra">
  <div class="damageDetails">
    <h2 class="title results_found" id="results_found">Found <strong>15</strong>
    offers in the category Extra from <strong>198,97</strong>, and they have:</h2>
    <div class="row" style="margin-bottom: 40px;">
      <span class="col-xs-6 col-sm-4 col-md-3 standar-offers">
      <i class="fa fa-check"></i>Human resources</span>
      <span class="col-xs-6 col-sm-4 col-md-3 standar-offers">
      <i class="fa fa-check"></i>Natural damages</span>
      <span class="col-xs-6 col-sm-4 col-md-3 standar-offers">
      <i class="fa fa-check"></i>Animal damages</span>
      <span class="col-xs-6 col-sm-4 col-md-3 standar-offers">
      <i class="fa fa-check"></i>Space damages</span>
    </div>
  </div><!--damageDetails-->
</div><!--tab_Extra-->
<div class="tab-boxes" id="tab_Premium">
  <div class="damageDetails">
    <h2 class="title results_found" id="results_found">Found <strong>8</strong>
    offers in the category Premium from <strong>358,79</strong>, and they have:</h2>
    <div class="row" style="margin-bottom: 40px;">
      <span class="col-xs-6 col-sm-4 col-md-3 standar-offers">
      <i class="fa fa-check"></i>Human resources</span>
      <span class="col-xs-6 col-sm-4 col-md-3 standar-offers">
      <i class="fa fa-check"></i>Natural damages</span>
      <span class="col-xs-6 col-sm-4 col-md-3 standar-offers">
      <i class="fa fa-check"></i>Animal damages</span>
      <span class="col-xs-6 col-sm-4 col-md-3 standar-offers">
      <i class="fa fa-check"></i>Space damages</span>
      <span class="col-xs-6 col-sm-4 col-md-3 standar-offers">
      <i class="fa fa-check"></i>Premium</span>
    </div>
  </div><!--damageDetails-->
</div><!--tab_Premium-->
```

I have also the pictures for better understanding:
[Basic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NAZh0.jpg)
[Extra](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gRDMx.jpg)

The site doesn't let me to put third picture for the premium link. But it's almost the same.

Comment: you're using bootstrap css so are you also using bootstrap.js?  if so you could use tabs or pills
https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/components/navs/#tabs

Answer (score 0):

I see you use Bootstrap, so you can use [Bootstrap tabs](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#tabs) component.

It do the same, all what you need change a little your code or if you want to use your own js code - use `display:none` like Bootstrap.

Comment: Thanks @Yaroslav Molchan but I dodn't know the details and how to use js code and this display:none that you said to me. And there is another problem also. In each change of the 3 Buttons are also changes below the textes some different calculating processes. Different prices on each button.

Answer (score 0):

You can use either. A suitable way to use both. 'active' class for the CSS of selected button. You can hide the tab boxes separately by 'display: none'.

```
<div class="col-xs-4">
     <div class="packet-offer" id="Basic">
         <div class="vertical-middle">
              <a class="tab-link col-xs-12" data-tab="tab_Basic" href="javascript:void(0);">Basic</a>
         </div>
     </div>
</div>
<div class="col-xs-4">
    <div class="packet-offer" id="Extra">
        <div class="vertical-middle">
            <a class="tab-link col-xs-12" data-tab="tab_Extra" href="javascript:void(0);">Extra</a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="col-xs-4">
    <div class="packet-offer" id="Premium">
        <div class="vertical-middle">
             <a class="tab-link col-xs-12" data-tab="tab_Premium" href="javascript:void(0);">Premium</a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

///Rest HTML

<script>

$(function() {
    $(".tab-link").click(fnuction() {
        var tab = $(this).attr("data-tab");
        $(".tab-link").removeClass("active");
        $(this).addClass("active");
        $(".tab-boxes").hide();
        $("#"+tab).show();
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: Thank you @Akshay Prakash. But I want to know if is also dynamic? I mean if this code is ready to handle calculating processes. Or I need some mix between PHP and HTML? I don't know.

Answer (score 0):

```js
$('.tab-link').click(function() {
  $('.tab-boxes').hide();
  $($(this).attr('href')).show();
})
```

```css
.tab-boxes {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="col-xs-4">
  <div class="packet-offer" id="Basic">
    <div class="vertical-middle">
      <a class="tab-link col-xs-12" href="#tab_Basic">Basic</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="col-xs-4">
  <div class="packet-offer" id="Extra">
    <div class="vertical-middle">
      <a class="tab-link col-xs-12" href="#tab_Extra">Extra</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="col-xs-4">
  <div class="packet-offer" id="Premium">
    <div class="vertical-middle">
      <a class="tab-link col-xs-12" href="#tab_Premium">Premium</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>


<div class="tab-boxes" id="tab_Basic">
  <div class="damageDetails">
    <h2 class="title results_found" id="results_found">Found <strong>15</strong> offers in the category Basic from <strong>98,97</strong>, and they have:</h2>
    <div class="row" style="margin-bottom: 40px;">
      <span class="col-xs-6 col-sm-4 col-md-3 standar-offers">
      <i class="fa fa-check"></i>Human resources</span>
      <span class="col-xs-6 col-sm-4 col-md-3 standar-offers">
      <i class="fa fa-check"></i>Natural damages</span>
    </div>
  </div>
  <!--damageDetails-->
</div>


<!--tab_Basic-->
<div class="tab-boxes" id="tab_Extra">
  <div class="damageDetails">
    <h2 class="title results_found" id="results_found">Found <strong>15</strong> offers in the category Extra from <strong>198,97</strong>, and they have:</h2>
    <div class="row" style="margin-bottom: 40px;">
      <span class="col-xs-6 col-sm-4 col-md-3 standar-offers">
      <i class="fa fa-check"></i>Human resources</span>
      <span class="col-xs-6 col-sm-4 col-md-3 standar-offers">
      <i class="fa fa-check"></i>Natural damages</span>
      <span class="col-xs-6 col-sm-4 col-md-3 standar-offers">
      <i class="fa fa-check"></i>Animal damages</span>
      <span class="col-xs-6 col-sm-4 col-md-3 standar-offers">
      <i class="fa fa-check"></i>Space damages</span>
    </div>
  </div>
  <!--damageDetails-->
</div>


<!--tab_Extra-->
<div class="tab-boxes" id="tab_Premium">
  <div class="damageDetails">
    <h2 class="title results_found" id="results_found">Found <strong>8</strong> offers in the category Premium from <strong>358,79</strong>, and they have:</h2>
    <div class="row" style="margin-bottom: 40px;">
      <span class="col-xs-6 col-sm-4 col-md-3 standar-offers">
      <i class="fa fa-check"></i>Human resources</span>
      <span class="col-xs-6 col-sm-4 col-md-3 standar-offers">
      <i class="fa fa-check"></i>Natural damages</span>
      <span class="col-xs-6 col-sm-4 col-md-3 standar-offers">
      <i class="fa fa-check"></i>Animal damages</span>
      <span class="col-xs-6 col-sm-4 col-md-3 standar-offers">
      <i class="fa fa-check"></i>Space damages</span>
      <span class="col-xs-6 col-sm-4 col-md-3 standar-offers">
      <i class="fa fa-check"></i>Premium</span>
    </div>
  </div>
  <!--damageDetails-->
</div>
<!--tab_Premium-->
```

Comment: Thank you @tye. But I want to know if is also dynamic? I mean if this code is ready to handle calculating processes. Or I need some mix between PHP and HTML? I don't know.